# Php variable and the variable assignment value returns different values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, variables

I am facing a really weird problem. The problem is shortly:

```
$x = some_object;
return response()->json($x)            =>  {}  
return response()->json(some_object)   =>  {some_object}
```

This is all of the code(The code goes inside the else statement):

```
public function checkCalls(Request $req)
{
    $active_call = VideoCall::where("receiver_id", (int) $req->input("user_id"));

    if ($active_call->where("call_situation", "call")->exists()) {
        $active_call = $active_call->first();

        $caller_id = $active_call->caller_id;
        $caller = User::where("id", $caller_id)->first();
        $caller_name = $caller->name;
        $caller_img = $caller->image;
        return response()->json([
            "friend" => $caller_id,
            "caller_name" => $caller_name,
            "caller_img" => $caller_img
        ]);
    } else if ($active_call->where("call_situation", "yes")->exists()) {
        return response()->json("gorusme yapıyor");
    } else if ($active_call->where("call_situation", "decline")->exists()) {
        $caller_id = $active_call->where("call_situation", "decline")->first()->caller_id;
        return response()->json("arama red edildi", $caller_id);
    } else {
        return response()->json("arama yok"); 
        //this code runs, I m changing here to get different returns  
    }
}
```

When I change inside the else brackets, this returns `true`

```
return response()->json(VideoCall::where("receiver_id", (int) $req->input("user_id"))->exists());
```

But this returns `false`:

```
return response()->json($active_call->exists());
```

`$active_call` returns an empty object for some reason.
The only explanation is that `$active_call` changes in `if()` parentheses but I can't find anything that can change it.
So why is this happening?

*Edit: Made the question clearer, added a shorter version of the problem.

*Edit 2: The code inside the else statement is running. I m changing that return statement to get different results

Comment: Please improve your question title; it is incredibly vague and is very unlikely to attract researchers that are suffering the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're re-assigning `$active_call` in your function:

```php
$active_call = $active_call->first();
```

It's no longer a `Builder`, but is instead a `VideoCall`.

So, this line:

```php
return response()->json($active_call->exists());
```

Is actually:

```php
return response()->json(VideoCall::where("receiver_id", (int) $req->input("user_id"))->first()->exists());
```

Note the additional `->first()`

Comment: No the code inside the else statement runs. It's not going in the first if statement. I should specify that in the question though. Its kinda confusing

Comment: I fixed it, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, I tried to run the code by commenting the re-assignment line. It's still the same.

Comment: Running `->where()` on a `Builder` modifies the builder. Try running `return response()->json($active_call->exists());` immediately after you assign `$active_call` and it will work as expected. The `->where()` calls in your `if` and `else if`s  are changing `$active_call` too.

Comment: Also, use `dd($active_call->toSql())` to debug your query. The query you're building isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Yes, when I call it immediately after it works fine. But I used `->where()` in a lot of places and I never faced a problem like this. How does it modify? I m not assigning `$active_call` to anything new. Doesn't `->where()` only returns a object?

Comment: In answer to your question of how it modifies the object, [here's the code that does it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L228). `->where()` returns the object after it's been modified.

Comment: Anyway, this is the correct answer to your question, and I'm sure you can see how to fix it now

Comment: Yes, it fixed, thank you for the explanation and the effort you made.